# SonarQube code coverage - exclude some classes

Tags: ant, sonarqube

Is there any way to purposefully increase Code Coverage value in SonarQube by excluding some classes.

Comment: Yes, you can use the sonar property `sonar.exclusions` to exclude the classes you don't want.

Comment: @SouravAtta <property name="sonar.exclusions" value="com/abc/demo/presentation/beans/**/*, com/abc/demo/presentation/interfaces/**/*, com/abc/demo/presentation/validator/**/*, com/abc/utility/**/*" />

I tried like the above but seems the code coverage doesn't increase.

Comment: Try to use `sonar.coverage.exclusions`. As **sonar.coverage.exclusions** is Comma-delimited list of file path patterns to be excluded from coverage calculations. Your pattern should be like this `sonar.coverage.exclusions=com/abc/demo/presentation/beans/**/*, com/abc/demo/presentation/interfaces/**/*, com/abc/demo/presentation/validator/**/*, com/abc/utility/**/*`

Comment: You welcome :) I have added the answer. Please accept the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to use **sonar.coverage.exclusions**.

As `sonar.coverage.exclusions` is Comma-delimited list of file path patterns to be excluded from coverage calculations. Your pattern should be like this:

```
sonar.coverage.exclusions=com/abc/demo/presentation/beans/**/*, com/abc/demo/presentation/interfaces/**/*, com/abc/demo/presentation/validator/**/*, com/abc/utility/**/*
```

Note: Documentation for this option was removed in 7.3 (Google: `site:docs.sonarqube.org "sonar.coverage.exclusions"`). But you can still see them when you open the administration pages for the project on Sonar -> "General Settings" -> "Analysis Scope". Look for the values after "Key:"

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude certain files in **sonar-project.properties** file:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/*.js,**/*.json,**/*.xml,**/*.png,**/*.sh,**/*.h,**/*.m,**/*.c,**/*.cpp,**/*.pdf,**/*.plist,Pods/**/*
sonar.swift.excludedPathsFromCoverage=.*Tests.*
```

Also, you can include specific files using:

```
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*Test*/**
sonar.test.inclusions=*.swift
```